# Lines over scatter plots in python with mplot3d in 3d

Tags: python, plot, 3d

I came over a problem: plotting line plots over scatter plots in python with `mplot3d`. The code as follows:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111,projection='3d')


ax.scatter(oX, oY, oZ)   
plt.show()
```

Gives this result:

[image]

This code:

```
for n in range(5):
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(8):
        y.append(oY[i*5+n])
        x.append(i)
    a, b = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
    print [b,a*8+b]
    ax.plot([0,8],[b,a*8+b],[n,n])
plt.show()
```

[image]

And finally:

```
ax.scatter(oX, oY, oZ)  
for n in range(5):
    x = []
    y = []
    for i in range(8):
        y.append(oY[i*5+n])
        x.append(i)
    a, b = np.polyfit(x,y,1)
    print [b,a*8+b]
    ax.plot([0,8],[b,a*8+b],[n,n])
plt.show()
```

[image]

As you can see, the images do not overlap. How exactly can I proceed solving this problem and mainly plotting lines over scatter plots in python.